# Bash - How to kill all the processes of the current user that meet a criteria?

Tags: bash, process

I am currently using `ps -o pid,cmd | awk '{if($2=="watch") print $1}' | xargs kill -1`.

I would like to expand the command to kill the processes of the current user.

What I got working is `ps -o uid,pid,cmd | awk '{if($1==1000 && $3=="watch") print $2}' | xargs kill -1` but I would like to replace $1==1000 with something like id -u but its not working.

Comment: Which OS/distribution and version do you use?

Comment: I don't want anything specific as currently I am using Red Hat Enterprise but might also use in the short future Ubuntu / Debian.

Comment: With Ubuntu and RHEL `ps -o uid,pid,cmd` lists only processes of current user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a simpler command like

```
pkill -U $USER watch
```

Note that you can target more than one user by using `-U user1,user2,...`

Comment: Please mention that the `-U` can be a comma separated list of users

Comment: Great one, way easier and simpler than what I've been using. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
ps -o uid,pid,cmd |
awk -v uid=$(id -u) '$1==uid && $3=="watch"{print $2}' |
xargs kill -1
```